# React button not visible on Safari iOS / CSS / HTML

Tags: html, css, ios, reactjs, web

I made a little hamburger button. This button is not shown on Safari iOS. On Windows Chrome and Firefox it is displayed, also on my Android device. I'm a beginner in web development and have already tried but couldn't find any solution. Maybe you know what the problem is.

React Component:

```
import React from "react";
import "./DrawerButton.css";

const drawerButton = (props: Props) => (
  <button onClick={props.onClick} className="drawer_button">
    <div className="drawer_button_line" />
    <div className="drawer_button_line" />
    <div className="drawer_button_line" />
  </button>
);

interface Props {
  onClick: () => void;
}

export default drawerButton;
```

CSS:

```
.drawer_button {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 24px;
    width: 23px;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.drawer_button_line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `-webkit-appearance: none` to your button CSS. If you don't add this property, safari will display their own default styled button (it's pretty ugly)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance

Answer (score 0):

Try adding inline styles, if some specific css is not implemented as safari stores some default styles in cache.